# Expert Spy Contract Glitch

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

So, one of the objectives in the Expert Spy Contract from Jungle Inferno is to get 5 kills in a single life without dying. I have gotten seven or eight kills in a single life, with no progress towards that bonus objective. I am using the Dead Ringer. Would this prevent progress towards it?

Comment: Try re-enabling the contract by switching to another one then back to that one.